# Why do I have another 7 day posting embargo despite for a question that's open and upvoted?

Tags: support

I've posted exactly 2 questions in the last 2 months.

The first one was closed and I got a 7 day lockout.

Two weeks later I posted a second question. It is still open and has 3 upvotes, yet I've been given another 7 day lockout.

Why am I getting more lockouts despite not having any questions closed or downvoted?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think anyone can give you a good answer because the exact mechanics are hidden and they won't reveal them to prevent abuse. But what you need to remember is that the post limitations are based on your entire post history (including deleted posts) and not just your most recent one.

If I was to make an educated guess I would say your entire post history is in such a state that you are limited to how often you can post a question which appears to be 7 days. As you ask more questions that get well received or post answers that get well received that will work towards removing that restriction.

Comment: +1 also relevant: [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th), especially "Are deleted posts taken into account too".

Comment: So, when someone goes through my entire post history and downvotes everything that I've ever posted they can get my account locked out, say someone who was upset when I  edited their question or reverted a change that I make, and the fact that these questions may be months old can still be held against me? Sounds like a system that's rife for abuse.

Comment: No, if someone goes through and downvotes all your posts, that will probably get automatically detected and reversed, and will count against their account in some way.

Comment: Just to add to that last point, if you get serial downvoted and the votes *aren't* reversed automatically, you can raise a custom mod flag to bring it to the mods' attention. The mods will then inform the community managers, who can reverse the downvotes manually.